# Reading score. What is a system?

Tags: theory, beginner

In piano class the teacher told the first pair of students to play the first system and the second pair of students to play the second system.  The piece played was eight measures long, binary form AABB, written out on two lines. The first line A repeated, the second line B repeated. The first pair played AA.  The second pair played BB.  What is meant by term "system."

Comment: Oddly enough,  I made it through over 30 years of lessons and ensemble playing before I bumped into someone who used this term!

Answer (score 5):

A "system" is just a line of music, and by "line" of music, we mean a *staff* line.

For a single-staff instrument, the first system will just be the first staff line of music, like so:

[image]

For a multi-staff instrument like the piano, the first system will be the line of music shown on the first grand staff. And since it's a grand staff, the first system actually includes two different staves, like so:

[image]

I assume the eight-measure piece in piano class was split up across two different lines of music, so the the first pair of students were to play the first line, while the second pair of students were to play the second line.

Comment: Just to make this a bit clearer: a "system" includes *all* the instruments that are playing at the same time, not just the two staves in a Grand Staff. In an orchestra score, often one system takes up the entire page. Also, in English, "staff line" often means "just one of the 5 lines of the staff". The term for the complete 5-line staff is just "staff". Some people use the word "line" when they really mean either "staff" or "system", but that is confusing. It is better *not* to use "line" unless you use another word to say what type of line you mean - there are also bar lines, 8va lines, etc.

Comment: @alephzero Yeah, this was a surprisingly hard answer to write. I've encountered people that also equate "staff" with "clef," and I wanted to make sure I didn't run into that problem.